# Set breakpoints and debug eval'd JavaScript

Tags: javascript, debugging

I<sup>*</sup> am using client-side JS to parse XML files and generate complex JS code to `eval` as a result. (Generating re-usable functions that are kicked off by a runtime.) However, I need to debug the code being generated, and would like to use Chrome's built-in breakpoints, stepping, watch windows, etc.

Is there an easier way to do this than:

- Dump the generated JS string to the console and/or window.
- Copy the JavaScript
- (optional) Run the JS through a prettifier like [JSBeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/).
- Paste the JS into a file that is loaded via `<script src="...">` in another web page.

<sup>* *actually, a friend of mine was doing this, not me*</sup>

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Instead of using `eval`, and instead of manually copy/pasting into a separate file, you can dynamically load the JS directly into the page that generated it by using a [data uri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) on a dynamically-created `<script>` element. With this approach, Chrome's Developer Tools (and Firebug) allow you to pick the data-URI as a script, turn on the Pretty Print, set breakpoints, and away you go.

```
var js = createMyJSCodeString();
addCode(js); // Right now! Debuggable!

// Dynamically evaluate JavaScript-as-string in the browser
function addCode(js){
  var e = document.createElement('script');
  e.type = 'text/javascript';
  e.src  = 'data:text/javascript;charset=utf-8,'+escape(js);
  document.body.appendChild(e);
}
```

Comment: Did you just... answer yourself? Sounded like you already talked about this in your question.

Comment: @TheZ Yes, I did. This is an [accepted practice on Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) for adding to the knowledge base. There is now even a checkmark to press for automatically adding an answer as you post the question, which is what I used here.

Comment: So, what does `createMyJSCodeString` do? You said it parses XML files?

Comment: @lbstr As I understand it, it runs through XML files and generates the contents of functions by concatenating strings for various child elements and such. (The XML is a custom programming language representation.) It would certainly possible to generate the functions as closures--without any strings/eval--but there is a belief that doing it once this way will make a noticeable impact on the end speed.

Comment: If you're debugging someone else's code, you can automatically see the error in the eval'd code by putting the call to addCode in a conditional breakpoint.

Comment: (in case I google this again.) This can also be used to debug errors with `new Function`