# Find where a syntax error occurs when new Function() fails

Tags: javascript, browser

To shortcut a long comment section on "don't use new Function" and/or "eval is evil", this question is about how to access, if possible, error information that is related to a `new Function()` constructor failing. It's mostly a question to discover a limit in what the browser will let me do when trying to exploit JavaScript to the extent that the spec and standard browser implementations allow. So with that disclaimer in place:

When evaluating code through a new Function() call, is there a way to find out where in the function's content a syntax error occurs, if illegal-syntax code is being evaluated? i.e.:

```
try {
  var generator = new Function(input);
  try {
    generator();
  }
  catch (runtimeError) {
    console.error("legal code; unforeseen result: ", runtimeError);
  }
}
catch (syntaxError) {
  console.error("illegal code; syntax errors: ", syntaxError);
}
```

When the building of the generator fails, is there a way to find out (from the browser, not using jslint or another external library) what the error was or where it occurred?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SyntaxError/prototype mentions that a SyntaxError has a `filename` and `linenumber` property, but these are undefined for dynamic code evaluated through a new Function() constructor from what I can tell, so relying on the error object itself seems not to be an option. Are there alternative ways to introduce the code to the browser so that the code, once we know it has syntax errors from a failing new Function call, can be used to find out where the problem is according to the JS engine used?

(Of course, if the goal was to simply find syntax errors, jslint as a preprocess step would be the go-to solution, but I'm more interested in whether or not browsers can in some way be made to report this information, even if in limited form like "there is SOME error on line/char ...")

Comment: Please do not do `new Function`. Instead just use `Function` without the `new` operator.

Comment: You're 5 years late to the party, but even then: no. `Function` is an object type, which when called as if it's a function does [_the same thing as `new Function`_](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.1) so advocating using the spec-defined "hides the details" call instead of calling `new Function` explicitly is a really weird thing to do. All the same error handling applies, so keep your code obvious, and use explicit calls.

Answer (score 4):

afaik impossible to find out where it occured. but you may want to see Exception.message to fetch information what the error was.

example: http://jsbin.com/IRoDiJIV/1/watch?js

Comment: I've found a solution, but hadn't considered catching errors in running the code, that's a useful addition.

Comment: That example is a runtime exception (specifically, a ReferenceError), not a SyntaxError! Btw, your example does indeed log where the error occured: `Error thrown at line 1, column 0 in <anonymous function>(): callundefinedFunction(); called from line 18, column 4 in <anonymous function>() in http://run.jsbin.com/runner: generator(); called from line 11, column 7 in http://run.jsbin.com/runner: (function(){`

Comment: it did? what property/method did you use on the Error?
could not find no info in the docu or in the example (ran in chrome)

Comment: Opera did bring that up as `runtimeError.stacktrace` property (though probably nonstandard).

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution myself using a simiar method to [setting breakpoints in evaled code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248126/set-breakpoints-and-debug-evald-javascript)

In chrome dev tools's sources panel, I put the following in a conditional breakpoint on the `new Function` line (since it's library code and I can't change it.)

```
(function(eval_js, load_js) {
  try {
    eval(eval_js);
  } catch (e) {
    (function addCode(js) {
      var e = document.createElement('script');
      e.type = 'text/javascript';
      e.src = 'data:text/javascript;charset=utf-8,' + escape(js);
      document.body.appendChild(e);
      console.warn("Inserted Script for ", js);
    })(load_js.replace(/;/g,";\n"));
    handlerCode = "";
    return false;
  }
  return false;
})("new Function('event', handlerCode)", handlerCode)
```

Comment: How do you get the linenumber of a syntax error in the `eval_js` from that?

Comment: @Bergi, it will load the handler_js code via a data uri in a new script element, that when run will give an error in the console which you can debug in chrome dev tools and firebug

Comment: But is it possible to access that error programmatically, without any debug consoles? That's what the OP wants to do.

Comment: @Bergi, I can't see anything in the question that says they want to access this programmatically. Mike says "I'm more interested in whether or not browsers can in some way be made to report this information". I think my answer fulfills that definition. If you did want to access it programmatically, having set up a conditional breakpoint the code that was originally evaluated dynamically is now run as a script, so you can access it by setting a window.onerror handler.

Comment: Ooops, you're right. I read too much into the question - probably because that is what *I* wanted to know :-)